# Magento 2 : Successful Order with Failed Payment

Tags: magento2, orders, payment

I am using an Indian payment gateway (PayTM), and payment gateway is working fine (in terms of successful payment and failed payment URLs). However, The payment succeed or failed, Magento still :

- creates an order with status processing,
- Send a confirmation email to the customer

How can I solve this issue? Basically I don't want order to be generated (or rather processed) if payment is failed. Or anything else other than sending confirmation email to customer.

Any help would be appreciated.

payTM RESPONSE code:

```php
class Response extends \One97\Paytm\Controller\Paytm
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $comment = "";
        $request = $_POST;
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
                if($key != "CHECKSUMHASH"){
                    $comment .= $key  . "=" . $val . ", \n <br />";
                }
            }
        }
        $errorMsg = '';
        $successFlag = false;
        $resMessage = $_POST['RESPMSG'];
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ORDERID');
        $order = $this->getOrderById($orderId);
        $orderTotal = round($order->getGrandTotal(), 2);
        $orderStatus = $this->getRequest()->getParam('STATUS');
        $resCode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('RESPCODE');
        $orderTxnAmount = $this->getRequest()->getParam('TXNAMOUNT');
        //print_r($request);
        if($this->getPaytmModel()->validateResponse($request, $orderId))
        {
            if($orderStatus == "TXN_SUCCESS" && $orderTotal == $orderTxnAmount){                
                // Create an array having all required parameters for status query.             
                $requestParamList = array("MID" => $_POST['MID'] , "ORDERID" => $orderId);

                // Call the PG's getTxnStatus() function for verifying the transaction status.
                $check_status_url = $this->getPaytmModel()->getStatusQueryUrl();                
                $responseParamList = $this->getPaytmHelper()->callAPI($check_status_url, $requestParamList);
                if($responseParamList['STATUS']=='TXN_SUCCESS' && $responseParamList['TXNAMOUNT']==$_POST['TXNAMOUNT'])
                {
                    $successFlag = true;
                    $comment .=  "Success ";
                    $order->setStatus($order::STATE_PROCESSING);
                    $order->setExtOrderId($orderId);
                    $returnUrl = $this->getPaytmHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success');
                }
                else{
                    $errorMsg = 'Paytm Transaction Failed ! Fraud has been detected';
                    $comment .=  "Fraud Detucted";
                    $order->setStatus($order::STATUS_FRAUD);
                    $returnUrl = $this->getPaytmHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/failure');
                }
            }else{
                if($resCode == "141" || $resCode == "8102" || $resCode == "8103" || $resCode == "14112"){
                    $errorMsg = 'Paytm Transaction Failed ! Transaction was cancelled.';
                    $comment .=  "Payment cancelled by user";
                    $order->setStatus($order::STATE_CANCELED);
                    $this->_cancelPayment("Payment cancelled by user");
                    //$order->save();
                    $returnUrl = $this->getPaytmHelper()->getUrl('checkout/cart');
                }else{
                    $errorMsg = 'Paytm Transaction Failed ! '.$resMessage;
                    $comment .=  "Failed";

                    $order->setStatus($order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW);
                    $returnUrl = $this->getPaytmHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/failure');
                }
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            $errorMsg = 'Paytm Transaction Failed ! Fraud has been detected';
            $comment .=  "Fraud Detucted";
            $order->setStatus($order::STATUS_FRAUD);
            $returnUrl = $this->getPaytmHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/failure');
        }
        $this->addOrderHistory($order,$comment);
        $order->save();
        if($successFlag){
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess( __('Paytm transaction has been successful.') );
        }else{
            $this->messageManager->addError( __($errorMsg) );
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sanjay,

Issue may be at logic of Paytm module.

There are must be  3 frontend urls in this module

**Redirection url** means the page where customer is ***landed after order place and before goes to Paytm site***

**Success url:** where paytm **is redirect to the customer** ***after successfully payment done at paytm***

**And another failure url:** where ***paytm is redirect to the customer after failure in  payment at paytm***

So, may **at Redirection action. Forcefully order status has been changed to Processing**.

So, you need ***stop to run this code*** and also. Change the status success action

Comment: Here is the code snippet (added to the main question) where PayTM controls the redirects. I don't see any place where PayTM is setting the status to success. (I could be wrong though.. )

Comment: Also, is there a way I can see the process flow (or redirects)?

Comment: so you have any other files at `Controller`?

Comment: Actually, this order is in "PAYMENT REVIEW" state which makes sense. but now the issue becomes 1. how should I send a link to the customer to complete the payment 2. Instead of showing order successful on screen, I want to show payment failed. Do I need to code this? This looks pretty basic logic and requirement, so maybe Magento already provides it.

Comment: @Sanjay have you resolved the issue???

Comment: @AmitBera I am facing same issue so can I get proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento 2 provides processing as default status for rediretion payment gateway.

You need to put

```
$order = $this->getOrderById($orderId); //load your order
$order->addStatusToHistory(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_NEW,__('Customer was redirected to PayTM'));
$order->save();
```

This will set your order in pending status once you redirected to gateway.
Your success and failure action will change the status upon payment success ot failure.

Thanks and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Need to put this where?

Comment: In your redirect controller action.

Comment: PayTM controller?

Comment: Please share how many controller actions are there? or please share all controller code or extension code.

Comment: Here is the link for PayTM extension. https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Magento_v2.x_Kit

It has the entire code including controllers..

Comment: @SanjayJethva If payment cancel url like website.in/paytm/processing/cancel/ how to redirect to home page?

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace in Redirect.php file

```
$order->setState("pending_payment")->setStatus("pending_payment");
            $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), "Customer was redirected to paytm.");
$order->save();
```

By:-

```
$order->setState("pending_payment")->setStatus("pending_payment");
            $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), "Customer was redirected to paytm.");
            //$order->save();
```

it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

For stopping mail for failed order, you have to write observer.

name : `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

```
if($order->getStatus() == 'confirmed'){
                $this->orderSender->send($order, true);

            }
```